# Is typecast required in malloc?

Tags: c, casting, malloc

What is the use of typecast in malloc? If I don't write the typecast in malloc then what will it return?  (Why is typecasting required in malloc?)

Answer (score 13):

I assume you mean something like this:

`int *iptr = (int*)malloc(/* something */);`

And in C, you do not have to (and should not) cast the return pointer from `malloc`. It's a `void *` and in C, it is implicitly converted to another pointer type.

`int *iptr = malloc(/* something */);`

Is the preferred form.

This does not apply to C++, which does not share the same `void *` implicit cast behavior.

Comment: @user615929 - what do you need more clearly explained? You do not need to cast the return `void *` from `malloc` since it can be freely, and implicitly, converted to other pointer types.

Comment: char *iptr = (char*)malloc(/* something);  means, it will type cast in to char ;             char *iptr =malloc(/* something); after allocating the size ... how it will type cast in to char?

Comment: u mean automatically it will type cast?

Comment: @user615929 - In C, pointers to `void` (`void *`) can be converted to any other pointer type without a cast, unlike pointers to other types (e.g., assigning a value of type `char *` to a variable of type `int *` *does* require an explicit cast).  Thus, the value returned by `malloc` will be automatically converted to the target pointer type, no cast necessary.  Note that in *very old* (pre-1989) versions of C, `malloc` returned `char *`, so an explicit cast *was* neccesary if you were assigning the result to a variable of a diffferent type.

Answer (score 6):

You should never cast the return value of `malloc()`, in C. Doing so is:

- Unnecessary, since `void *` is compatible with any other pointer type (except function pointers, but that doesn't apply here).
- Potentially dangerous, since it can hide an error (missing declaration of the function).
- Cluttering, casts are long and often hard to read, so it just makes the code uglier.

So: there are no benefits, at least three drawbacks, and thus it should be avoided.

Comment: I didn't get the second point. Could you please explain further ?

Comment: The second point is wrong. If you forget to include <stdlib.h> it does not matter whether you cast the result of malloc or not, you get a warning "implicit function declaration" (without any additional switches to most compilers). If you produce and ignore warnings - it is your problem, not the laguage, not the compiler, not the casting - it is you. The first point is a dry fact, no argue about that. All other points are only about your personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

You're not *required* to cast the return value of `malloc`. This is discussed further in the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html and http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html .

Answer (score 1):

Just because malloc returns a `void`* and since `void*` has not defined size you can't apply pointer aritmetic on it. So you generally cast the pointer to the data type your allocated memory block actually points.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are correct, I just have an advice:

- don't play with pointers - which *malloc()* returns - too much, cast them to a specified type asap;
- if you need to do some math with them, cast them to *char**, so ptr++ will mean what you except: add 1 to it (the size of the datatype will be added, which is 1 for char).