# calloc typecasting to pointer to pointer

Tags: c

What does this statement mean?

```
//allocated memory for Device info

(*PppsCoreStructure)->psDeviceDetails=(sDeviceDetails **)calloc(CORE_DEVICEINFO_SIZE, sizeof(sDeviceDetails*));
```

I know that '(*PppsCoreStructure)->psDeviceDetails' is a pointer to pointer. But I am not being able to imagine how calloc can return pointer to pointer? I'm a beginner please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `(*PppsCoreStructure)->psDeviceDetails` is declared with type `sDeviceDetails **`
- The return value of `calloc()` is of type `void*`
- `(sDeviceDetails **)calloc(...)` casts the return value of `calloc` to be of type `sDeviceDetails **`

In the C++ language this type cast is essential, although in C++ one would normally not be using `calloc` and would probably be using C++ casts.

In the C language the type cast is not needed because a `void*` pointer is assignment compatible with all other pointer types.

---

In a comment you state

> But I want know how `sDeviceDetails*` is different from `sDeviceDetails**`

and I suspect that this is in fact your real question.

The answer is simple enough: `T*` is a pointer-to-T and `T**` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-T.

Comment: I mean as I know, calloc/malloc creates a new space and reurns its address to a pointer. So T* is correct. I understood. But for T**, calloc/malloc should create new space, assign it to a pointer. And again, that pointer's address will be assigned to T**. What I thought is correct? If correct, what about that middle pointer?

Comment: @SHRI Your call to `calloc` only allocates the array of pointers. You must then allocate each pointer in that array.

Answer (score 3):

This call to `calloc` allocates sufficient space for `CORE_DEVICEINFO_SIZE` pointers to `sDeviceDetails` objects. `calloc` returns a simple memory buffer that can be used to store anything; in this case, pointers.

(Note that relying on `calloc` to return buffers filled with null pointers is not portable: it returns zero-filled buffers, but the null pointer is not necessarily all zeroes. It is on common platforms, though.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir, but I want know how (sDeviceDetails *)calloc is different from  (sDeviceDetails **)calloc.

Comment: @SHRI: as I explained, `calloc` is used here to allocate space for pointers to `sDeviceDetails`. You'd use a cast `sDeviceDetails*` when allocating space for a `struct sDeviceDetails`, or an array of those.

Comment: `(sDeviceDetails *)calloc(...)` requires that `sDeviceDetails` is an array or pointer type (or that you only asked to `calloc` a single element -- i.e. CORE_DEVICEINFO_SIZE = 1).  Because `calloc` allocates several sequential chunks of memory, its return values are pointers to pointers the same way that pointers-to-arrays are like pointers-to-pointers

Answer (score 3):

The function allocates an array of pointers. CORE_DEVICEINFO_SIZE is the number of pointers in this array.

(sDeviceDetails **) means that the programmer who wrote the code doesn't know how void-pointer casts work in the C language. The cast is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: Sorry, why is it redundant to stop compiler warnings? It makes the real warnings possible to see no?

Comment: This typecast _removes_ the real warnings, for example if you accidently try to store a pointer-to-pointer inside a pointer. That's why this is bad practice. (C++ is another matter, but this question is about C.) [Read any number of posts about it on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993327/is-typecast-required-in-malloc)