# what does (int *) before malloc mean?

Tags: c, memory-management

what does the (int *) do in the following code?

```
int *ptr = (int *) malloc(10 * sizeof (int));
```

i'm new to C and i've seen the above code with and without the (int *) so im wondering what it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is typecast required in malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993327/is-typecast-required-in-malloc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That means "cast a `void*` pointer into a `int*` pointer" - `malloc()` returns `void*` and you ask the compiler to treat that `void*` as if it was `int*`. This construct around `malloc()` is only needed in C++ code, and is [totally unneeded and even evil in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565496/57428) because it can cause rather subtle yet devastating errors.