# C unknown access violation at first index in array

Tags: c, access-violation, assign

Below I have a method that constructs a permutated string of a given string (str).
I don't really know why but sometimes while debugging I receive the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x01282665 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation 
writing     location 0x00000000.
```

when trying to assign ('u') at index 0 in ret_str (ret_str[l]=elem[0])

```
unsigned char* getPermStr(long length,unsigned char* strt,unsigned char* elem){
    unsigned char* ret_str;
    long l = 0;
    ret_str = (unsigned char*) calloc(length,sizeof(unsigned char));
    while(l < length){
        if(elem < (strt+length-1)){
            ret_str[l]=elem[0];  // ACCESS VIOLATION HERE
            elem+=1;
        }else{
            ret_str[l]=elem[0];
            elem = strt;
        }
        l+=1; 
    }
    return ret_str;
}
```

I don't see why the access violation occurs... I'm within the bounds of my ret_str so what is wrong?
BTW: The string ret_str is free'd after the function call.

UPDATE:
There was no problem with elem. The reason was that I allocated memory while there was no memory left on the heap for dynamic allocation (due of lots of memory leaks) so calloc returned a NULL pointer. That's why the error occured.

Comment: If I were you, I'd check if ret_str and elem are not NULL ;)

Comment: It's telling you that ret_str is null. Think about why that might be.

Comment: So that means that calloc didn't allocate memory. Elem is not NULL in this case...

Comment: The root cuase for the error most probably lies in the memory referred by `elem`.

Comment: There was no problem with elem. The reason was that I allocated memory while there was no memory left on the heap for dynamic allocation (due of lots of memory leaks) so calloc returned a NULL pointer. That's why the error occured.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether elem is null. If it is null your function should return an error code.

Comment: If not `NULL` `elem` most certainly points to memory not belonging to the process.

Comment: There was no problem with elem. The reason was that I allocated memory while there was no memory left on the heap for dynamic allocation (due of lots of memory leaks) so calloc returned a NULL pointer. That's why the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

`ret_str = (unsigned char*) calloc(length,sizeof(unsigned char));`
Change this line to

```
ret_str = malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char));
if(ret_str == NULL){ return "" ;}
//--whatever
while(l < length){
        if(elem < (strt+length-1)){
            ret_str[l]=elem[0];  // ACCESS VIOLATION HERE
            elem+=1;
        }else{
            ret_str[l]=elem[0];
            elem = strt;
        }
        l+=1; 
    }
```

Also make sure, elem is accessible. Chances are, elem isn't initialised.

Comment: It's giving the error on write, so it's gotta be ret_str not elem.

Comment: In C, it is preferable not to use explicit typecasting when using malloc/calloc.

Comment: no its not preferable nor necessary. Also there are certain problems using "malloc"

Comment: @askmish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993327/is-typecast-required-in-malloc read this to know why its not preferred to typecast malloc.

Comment: I wanted to say that there's no problem in calloc or malloc in OP's code.

Comment: @askmish its obvious he isn't checking for NULL. Other than that, there seems to be NO problem with the code. You think he is hiding something?