# C Syntax Explanation

Tags: c

I am studying C Language I need some explanation about a code segments,

```
int *p;
p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

What does the (int *) means and whats really happening when you execute the above Code?

Comment: Did you try searching on some search engine?

Comment: it means you shouldn't do it...

Comment: The `(int *)` means the person who wrote this does not know proper C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`(int *)` is a so called *cast* operator. It is used to convert the value on the right side of the operator to the type enclosed in parenthesis.

Here, it is used to convert the `void *` pointer returned by `malloc()` to an `int *`, i.e. a pointer to an integer.

This is a very bad usage, and [you should not do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` has return type `void*`, which reads as pointer-to-void which means pointer-to-something.

`p` has type `int*`, so pointer-to-int. In order to assign the result of `malloc` into `p`, you need to convert `int*` into `void*` somehow.

If you write:

```
int* p = malloc(...)
```

the conversion happens automatically ("implicit conversion").

If you, for some reason, decide to write:

```
int* p = (int*) malloc(...)
```

the result is the same, but the conversion is explicit (i.e. a "cast").

Answer (score 1):

Try this link [man malloc](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/malloc/)

In C, there is no need of typecasting in `malloc`so write directly

`p = malloc(sizeof(int));`

FYI , this `(int *)` is nothing but the typecast. Since many functions return `void*`
so it needs to typecast in the respective type for further manipulations with pointers.

In case of malloc it's implicitely taken care of

`(type)` is called type cast operator in C.

suppose for example,

```
int a;
float b = 11.4;
```

You want to put the integral value of `b`in `a`. Use type casting

`a = (int)b`

Comment: True, but I think it's always a good thing to do the implicit conversion, you know what you are doing this way.

Comment: *"Using typecast you can convert any type to any other type."*, keyword: *type*. It doesn't convert the *values* except when the standard says so (e.g.: for numeric types).

Comment: @YasassriChaturangeRatnayake:  For more .. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993327/is-typecast-required-in-malloc

Comment: @Joze No, it is almost always a bad thing. Please see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993327/is-typecast-required-in-malloc and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/ . It can be an acceptable compromise to cast in some circumstances, but not because “you know what you are doing”. One demonstrates that one knows what one is doing by not casting the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: If you have to use your code in C++ aswell it's really useful for compatibility. But I agree with argument. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) the documentation on malloc.

You're allocating a block of memory the size of an int (this value may change depending on the system/compiler combo).

The (int *) casts the right hand side as an int *, which isn't necessary in C, you just need the malloc.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p;  // pointer to an integer
p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); // assignment of enough memory for an integer
```

The `(int *)` part is called typecasting, you're telling the compiler:

"I know malloc() gives me a void *, but I'm going to assign it to something else".

There are useful reasons to typecast, but it can be dangerous too. In this case since `malloc()` returns a `void *` you don't need to typecast because it's automatically and safely converted to other pointer types.

Answer (score 1):

Unwind already gave you the answer, but I want to expand on it a bit.

In C, some types are not *compatible*; you can't directly assign a value of type `T` to a variable of type `Q`; for example, you can't assign a pointer to `int` to a variable that's type pointer to `double`:

```
double *q;
int *p;
...  
q = p; // will cause a diagnostic to be issued
```

If you really need to make that assignment, though, you can use a *cast expression*, which converts the value to the target type:

```
q = (double *) p;
```

This tells the compiler to convert the value of `p` to pointer to `double` and assign the result to `q`.

In the original, K&R version of C, `malloc` returned `char *`, so if you wanted to assign the result of `malloc` to a pointer of a different type, you had to apply the cast:

```
int *p = (int *) malloc(SIZE);
```

That changed in 1989, when the first C standard was introduced.  That version introduced a `void *` type to act as a "generic" pointer type.  Values of type `void *` can be assigned to other pointer types directly, without need of a cast.  So, as of C89 and later, you can simply write

```
int *p = malloc(SIZE);
```

This was not only cleaner, it was also safer; if you forgot to include `stdlib.h` or otherwise didn't have a declaration for `malloc` in scope, the compiler would assume that `malloc` returned an `int` value and generate code accordingly.  Since an `int` value can't be directly assigned to a pointer type, you would get a diagnostic.  If you added the cast, however, that warning would be suppressed, and you would potentially have issues at runtime.

The 1999 standard got rid of the implicit `int` assumption, so that's no longer a real danger, but it's still better style to leave the cast off of a `malloc` call.